# Как с помощью \b убрать \n

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Хочу убрать \n из консоли при помощи \b

Получился у меня вот такой код:

```
Console.Write("frfr\n\b\b");
Console.Write("ss");
```

Но к сожалению он не работает, и в консоль пишется следующее:

**frfr

ss**

Comment: `\b` просто двигает курсор на 1 позицию влево.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо, так и сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно. В консоли `backspace` действует только в рамках текущей строки, он не может перейти на предыдущую строку.
После `\n` у вас начинается новая строка, и только в пределах этой новой строки вы можете "отменить" какие-то символы с помощью `\b`.
В текстовых редакторах вы, конечно, можете с помощью клавиши `Backspace` попасть на предыдущую строку, но консоль - это не редактор, она эмулирует "пишущую машинку" или что-то вроде того.

Comment: Сейчас нашёл такой скрипт на python написанный: https://github.com/AkaiRep/video-to-ascii/blob/main/video-to-ascii.py, там видео проигрывается в консоли, и каждый кадр заменяет друг друга, я не уверен, что там использовалось \b. Возможно вы знаете как реализовать подобный функионал

Comment: @alex, [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-6.0)